# Label displays punctuation incorrectly with RightToLeft

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to learn C# and .NET by creating a calculator app. However, I'm seeing some weird behavior with WinForms label and punctuation. My app has a series of number buttons, a "period" button for decimals, and various operators. When you press a button, I add the value to the label that is displaying the value:

```
displayLbl.Text += selectedButton.Text;
```

or

```
displayLbl.Text += ".";
```

The label has RightToLeft set to "true" to mimic the display of a typical calculator.

However, when a period first appears in the label, it appears *ahead* of the rest of the numbers that were added before it. For example, it will look like ".456" even though the "456" was added earlier. As soon as you add another number, the period will then appear back in its right place like "456.7".

This also happens with the negative sign (-). If you add "-478" to the label, it will appear as "478-".

This seems really buggy. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You don't want "RightToLeft", you probably want "TextAlignment.Right"

Comment: Yep, the TextAlign property made it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set RightToLeft to "No" and then did the following and it worked beautifully:

```
this.displayLbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.It will also help others to solve the similar issue.